# ng-select with async data from a BehaviourSubject stays empty

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ngselect

I'm trying to use `<ng-select>` to implement a product filter. The filter values (brands) come from an `Observable` (HTTP request). I'm using a `BehaviourSubject` that I've bound to the `ng-select`. And nothing never appear in the dropdown list, it keeps showing "No item found"...

(I'm using Angular 16.2 and ng-select 11.1)

HTML

```
<ng-select [items]="brands$ | async" 
                placeholder="Marques"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedBrands" 
                bindLabel="label"
                [multiple]="true"
                class="input-field">

                <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-item$="item$" let-index="index">
                    <input id="item-{{index}}" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item$.selected"/> {{item.name}}
                </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

TS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-grid',
  templateUrl: './product-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-grid.component.css']
})
export class ProductGridComponent implements OnInit {

  brands$: BehaviorSubject<Brand[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Brand[]>([]);
  selectedBrands: Brand[] = []

  constructor(private pss: ProductStoreService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pss.brands$.subscribe((brands:Brand[]) => {
      console.log(brands.length + ' items') // this logs "9 items", as expected
      this.brands$.next(brands)
    })
  }

}
```

The array of brands is very basic and looks like this

```
[{
  entityID: 1,
  label: "Adidas"
},...]
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence)? `ngAfterContentInit` could do the trick

Comment: same result, still empty...

Comment: Your code seems to work fine except you are using the wrong property to display the label (using `name` instead of `label`). [Broken](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77195970-original?file=src%2Fmain.ts) | [Working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77195970-asdf?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: you're right that I was not using the right property but still, it keeps saying "no item found" and when I look at the DOM, there is no <option> element at all

Comment: I put your same code in the StackBlitz... :-\

Comment: Also, you don't need `BehaviorSubject` or `ngOnInit` at all.  Just declare `brands$ = this.pss.brands$;`;

Comment: [Simplified](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77195970-simplified?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Ok the mistake was from the `pss` service. The BehaviourSubject was passing the value of the same object (an array in which I was adding / deleting brands). So from ng-select, I think it was only seeing the same array, without checking if items in it have changed